# Automatically resizing text with window size in tkinter calculator

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been working on a tkinter calculator in Python 3.8, with basic buttons and an entry field. I want the text in the buttons and entry field to increase (or decrease) size with the window automatically, in proportion with the buttons themselves -- have yet to work on the entry field font sizes -- and, despite trying for a while, have failed. At certain sizes, the font collapses to the minimum size (see code below) or starts phasing rapidly. It also collapses to minimum size when the window is moved.

[image: Calculator original size]

[image: Calculator at another size]

```
# Default font size
fontsize = tkFont.Font(size=11)

def font_change(event):
    # Base size
    normal_width = 418
    normal_height = 295

    # Screen
    screen_width = event.width
    screen_height = event.height

    # Get percentage of screen size from Base size
    percentage_width = screen_width / (normal_width / 100)
    percentage_height = screen_height / (normal_height / 100)

    # Make a scaling factor
    scale_factor = ((percentage_width + percentage_height) / 2) / 100

    # Set the fontsize based on scale_factor,
    # if the fontsize is less than minimum_size
    # it is set to the minimum size
    
    # font_size is the variable to store actual size
    minimum_size = 8
    if scale_factor > minimum_size/18:
        font_size = int(18 * scale_factor)
    
    else:
        font_size = minimum_size

    fontsize.configure(size = font_size)
```

I bind the function to an event:

```
root.bind("<Configure>", font_change)
```

Example of a button,

```
decimal = Button(
    root,
    text=".",
    command=lambda: press("."),
    font = fontsize, 
    height = 2,
    width=7)
decimal.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=NW + NE + SW + SE)
```

It would be appreciated if someone can help me out.

Comment: So what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Start by checking out [Making the root window resizeable](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/root-resize.html)

Comment: @Omid Ketabollahi The font changes were sporadic instead of smooth, ie, becoming disproportionately large or small, but Tls Chris's answer cleared it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I constructed a test GUI with two Labels.  `root.bind( "&LT;Configure&GT;", func )` is fired each time root **or any of it's children** resize. Code below.  When the Labels fire the configure event the font is minimised.  Which fires the configure event again, even smaller etc.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font


root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry( "200x100" )

fontsize = font.Font( size = 11 )

tk.Label( root, text = 'Test', font = fontsize ).grid( padx = 5, pady = 5 )
tk.Label( root, text = 'Another Test', font = fontsize ).grid( padx = 5, pady = 5 )

def font_change(event):

    print( event.widget, event )  # See what is happening

    # Base size
    normal_width = 200
    normal_height = 100

    # Screen
    screen_width = event.width
    screen_height = event.height
    print( event.widget, event )

    
    # Get percentage of screen size from Base size
    percentage_width = screen_width / (normal_width / 100)
    percentage_height = screen_height / (normal_height / 100)

    minimum_size = 8

    # Make a scaling factor
    scale_factor = ((percentage_width + percentage_height) / 2) / 100

    # Set the fontsize based on scale_factor,
    # if the fontsize is less than minimum_size
    # it is set to the minimum size
    
    # font_size is the variable to store actual size
    
    if scale_factor > minimum_size/18:
        font_size = int(18 * scale_factor)
    
    else:
        font_size = minimum_size

    fontsize.configure( size = font_size )

root.bind( '<Configure>', font_change )

root.mainloop()
```

One option is to replace the print statement in the above code with

```
if event.widget != root:
    return None  # Jump out of the function if the widget firing configure isn't root
```

Another option would be to read the `root` width and height in the `font_change` function, not take the width and height from event.

Comment: Thank you, reading the root dimensions instead of the event and using the snippet you provided below fixed it. I think I understood the mistake I was making